# RDLC Formula to add data field values while checking for conditions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, expression, reporting

I have the following DataBase table

```
Fabric(FabID,Category,PricePerYard,Yardage,TransportCost,Date)
```

I have genarated a report using that table with visual studio 2013 reportViewer.
Now I want to add another summary table at the bottom of my report. So in that summary table I want to display total yardage sold for each category separately. Table is as follows,

```
__________________________________________________________________
|                  Fabric Purchasing Summary                     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Cotton      |     Nylone     |    Polyester    |    Ponteroma
_________________________________________________________________
Yardage |   **X**     |                |                 |
Cost    |             |                |                 |
```

What I want to know here is What should be the formula I should write in Cell **X**?
For an example if I want to write it in SQL, It would be something like this,

```
select SUM(yardage)
from Fabric
Where category = 'Cotton'
```

I don't understand how can I write that in RDLC as an Expression. Please Help.
And please ask if you need to clarify anything..

Comment: you have to create a dataset -- a dataset can be defined as a query against the database.